# htaccess <Directory> deny from all apache2 ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

How can I prevent direct URL access for files and folders on apache web server ?
lets say I have folder like

mysite.me/img
that folder contains a lot of files like jpg php pdf mp4 etc...

How to prevent surfers from direct accessing those files and folders inside img folder from browser URL ?
i'm on ubuntu server and using :  Apache/2.4.18
i try to add some .htaccess file to my folder but din;t work 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the `mod_rewrite` module on apache first. To enable the module on Ubuntu:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that, set the directive `AllowOverride` of the directory, has the minimum configuration to `AllowOverride FileInfo Options`. You may find this directive in the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, `<Directory>` block.

Then, update your .htaccess as follows, all the traffic will route to index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: i'm using just html , css ,js , no php on my  site ??

Comment: What do you expect when someone access the folders / files? Do you wish  all the folders / files response 404 not found error or just some of them? Or you will handle it manually with dynamic script?

Comment: i want when some one try to get direct access to folders that contains img and video , get error 404 , i have two floders : img and images ,

Comment: I think you want to disable directory browsing? settings directive `Options -Indexes`, when someone access your directories, should give the forbidden error

Comment: Yeah thats right , but where i should put this ? Options -Indexes

Comment: add this to apache.conf. enclose it with `<directory>` directive. `<Directory "/var/www/some_directory">Options -Indexes</Directory>`

Comment: i mv to /etc/apache/apache2.conf   
and i find : 

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
But my website files , index / img / images , on /var/www/html/x

Comment: you are enabling directory browsing under the folder `/var/www`. If you wish to disable just for some folder, you should try to add `<Directory "/var/www/some_directory">Options -Indexes</Directory>`. Otherwise, should remove `Indexes` to remove directory browsing under the folder `/var/www`